How to call the Azure DevOps Identities Rest service using az devops invoke
How do I call this service using az devops invoke?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1
Specifically with the following query parameters:
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{orgName}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue={identity}&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.1
When I access this in a browser it returns data. I've been trying to do the same with the cli:
az devops invoke `
--query-parameters searchFilter=General filterValue=$($identity_name) queryMembership=None `
--org "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$orgName" `
--area IMS `
--resource Identity `
--api-version 7.1

I get the following warning and error:
The Azure DevOps Extension for the Azure CLI does not support Azure DevOps Server.
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Is my answer below helpful for you? Have you tried as the sample of the script showed in the answer? @JDH

I can reproduce the same error when using the same script as yours.

There are two mistakes in your script:

The correct value of '--org' should be the URL of Azure DevOps organization "https://dev.azure.com/$orgName".

The correct value of '--resource' should be 'Identities'.


So, you need to update your script like as below.
$pat="xxxx"
$orgName="xxxx"
$identity_name = "xxxx"

Write-Output $pat | az devops login --org https://dev.azure.com/$orgName

az devops invoke `
--org https://dev.azure.com/$orgName `
--query-parameters searchFilter=General filterValue=$identity_name queryMembership=None `
--area IMS `
--resource Identities `
--api-version 7.1




This resolved my issue. Please help me understand how to find the area and resource. I did an az devops invoke, dumped to a file and searched by the routeTemplate based on the URI in the doc. Now that I have the Area and Resource, I found the routeTemplate is "_apis/{resource}/{identityId}". How does that correlate to "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?api-version=7.1"? It has no identityID parameter.

@JDH, The '{identityId}' is an optional parameter of the API "Identities - Read Identities". When calling the API, you can use the optional parameter 'identityIds' to pass one or more user IDs on the HTTP URI. See the example of "By Ids".

shouldn't there be an endpoint with a routeTemplate without the optional identityId then? When I search the results do not include the Identities resource:
($endpoints | where {$_.routeTemplate -match "^_apis/{resource}$"}) | select -Property area, resourceName | sort area, resourceName
